# Center button between two images, vertically in percent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve this behavior:
[image]

- images are `img-fluid`, cause they need to scale across Bootstrap breakpoints
- the layout must always be like the mockup, both when images are small or large (button doesnt need to scale)

Since elements can't span across `div`s, I tried putting the button in the first column and setting it to `position: absolute` + many variants of props, but no way I could get the result I need.

**I don't need to use 2 `col`s at any cost, as long as it is all inside a `row`, i can do anything, this is just my attemp**

---

Some attempts:

Starting point without `button`:

```
<div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

Attempt 1:

```
<div class="row py-3">
    <div style="position: absolute" class="text-center h-auto" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;">
        <a class="btn btn-success text-white px-5">Hi guys</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="w-100">
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid mr-3">
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid ml-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Attempt 2:

```
<div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col">
        <a class="btn btn-success text-white px-5" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;">Hi guys</a>
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

And many others ...

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/693x678" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-success text-white px-5">Hi guys</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="row some-row">
  <div class="col">...</div>
  <div class="col">...</div>
  <a class="btn some-btn"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.some-row {
  position: relative;
}

.some-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: the button needs to be centered horizontally, and most of all the distance from the bottom can't be a fixed value in px, it needs to be in % of the current `img` height

Answer (score 1):

This solution makes the assumption that your button is placed inside the first column as per your own attempt. In this case, all you need for the button to be placed in the middle of the two columns is to use `parentWidth - 0.5 * buttonWidth`. A combination of `left` and `transform` achieves that:

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"), function (img) {
    img.src = "https://placehold.it/693x500";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cutt.ly/Twe8un2"/>

<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col">
    <img src = "https://placehold.it/693x300" class = "img-fluid">
    <a class = "btn btn-danger text-white">Custom Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class = "col">
    <img src = "https://placehold.it/693x300" class = "img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear, but I meant the opposite: the layout must always be like the mockup, no matter what the size of the images is

Comment: That's what my example does, Sergio.

Comment: Yes, after the edit. Someone gave me the perfect answer before all the others. I gave you an up-vote tho, so it should be fine :)

Comment: My answer hasn't changed with the edit. I merely created a working snippet to showcase it, because I had originally posted it from my phone. Upvoting or accepting the answer is irrelevant. I'm fine as long as it helps someone.

Comment: Yes, at first your answer wasn't in `%`, it was in `em`. And when i first checked for replies the first one in `%` was the one I chose, and that one already had a runnable code snippet too, so it was fast to check the result. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/bXYVwe) is a pen i did using a grid layout to replicate your mockup.
I used Grid because they make it easy to superpose elements and to organise a 2d layout.

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows : min-content 150px 20%;
    grid-template-columns : 45% 5% 5% 45%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
 }
```

The images only need one row but to position the button as desired I made 3. The 150px one being for the button. For the images i just need to span them accross the 3 rows.
For the column, as i need the button to be centered above the images, i made 4 of them. Each image span the 2 outside columns respectively and the button the 2 'inside' columns.

```
 .img1 {
   grid-row: 1/4;
   grid-column: 1/3;
 }

 .img2 {
   grid-row: 1/4;
   grid-column: 3/5;
 }

 .button1 {
   grid-row: 2/3;
   grid-column: 2/4;
 }
```

Obviously you can adjust the pourcentages and sizes to fit your need more precisly.
Note : The *row* you were talking about would be the grid container in this example.